# Expected argument of type "string", "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" given

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I'm using `collectiontype` for the tickets field in the `formbuilder` and trying to add server-side validation for the same. But I'm getting some errors only while adding the Assert validation.

My Entity:

```
/**
* @Assert\Length(
* min = 1,
* max = 10,
* minMessage = "Atlest one ticket to be added",
* maxMessage = "Not allowed"
* )
*
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EventTicket", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
*/
public $tickets;
```

My Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('tickets', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EventTicketType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true
        ]
    );
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Expected argument of type "string",
> "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" given.

Answer (score 3):

`@Assert\Length` is a String constraint and can't be used for collection type. You need to use `@Assert\Count` for collection type. This is how it should look like:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Count(
 *      min = 1,
 *      max = 10,
 *      minMessage = "At least one ticket to be added",
 *      maxMessage = "Not allowed"
 * )
  * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\EventTicket", inversedBy="events", cascade={"persist"})
 */
public $tickets;
```